# Manually reverse string not working

Tags: php

I am trying to reverse a string without using `strrev()`. I thought this would be a simple task:

```
$str = 'I am a string';
$rev = '';

for($i = 0, $len = strlen($str), $j = $len -1; $i < $len; $i++, $j--) {
    $rev += $str[$j];
}

echo $rev;
```

Result is `0`. Why is this?

When I do this:

```
$str = 'I am a string';
$rev = '';

for($i = 0, $len = strlen($str), $j = $len -1; $i < $len; $i++, $j--) {
    echo $str[$j];
}
```

I get: `gnirts a ma I`

Why is the second array returning the desired result but the first one is returning the wrong result, `0`?

Comment: `+=` is an arithmetic addition; `.=` is what you want for concatenation

Comment: @MarkBaker man I was thinking in Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php if you want to concatenate strings its the `.` operator, so instead of `+=` you'll want a `.=`

Answer (score 1):

You use `.` for concatenation and not `+` which is just for addition:

```
$rev .= $str[$j];
```